# Passing na.strings to dbWriteTable

Tags: database, r, sqlite, sqldf, rsqlite

I'm trying to run the following command in R in order to read a local tab-delimited file as a SQLite database:

```
library(RSQLite)
banco <- dbConnect(drv    = "SQLite",
                   dbname = "data.sqlite")
dbWriteTable(conn       = banco,
             name       = "Tarefas",
             value      = "data.tsv",
             sep        = "\t",
             dec        = ",",
             na.strings = c("", NA),
             row.names  = FALSE,
             header     = TRUE)
```

However, the statements above yield the following error:

> Error in read.table(fn, sep = sep, header = header, skip = skip, nrows
>   = nrows,  :    formal argument "na.strings" matched by multiple actual arguments

Which makes me think I'm not being able to pass `na.strings` explicitly as a `read.delim` argument. Running `dbWriteTable` without this argument gives me "RS-DBI driver: (RS_sqlite_import: ./data.tsv line 17696 expected 20 columns of data but found 18)". This is understandable, since I've checked line 17696 and it is almost completely blank.

Another test run using `sqldf` also gives me an error:

```
> read.csv2.sql(file      = "data.tsv",
+               sql       = "CREATE TABLE Tarefas AS SELECT * FROM FILE LIMIT 5",
+               dbname    = "data.sqlite",
+               header    = TRUE,
+               row.names = FALSE)
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such table: FILE)
```

Which I believe is an unrelated error, but still very confusing for someone who's pretty much an absolute SQL noob such as myself. Runnin `read.csv.sql` instead gives me this error:

> `Error in read.table(fn, sep = sep, header = header, skip = skip, nrows = nrows,  : 
>   more columns than column names`

So is there a way to pass `na.strings = c("", NA)` at `dbWriteTable`? Is there a better way to read 10 GB tab-delimited files into R aside from `sqldf` and `RSQLite`? I've already tried `data.table` and `ff`.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but what happens if you try `na.strings = c("","NA")`?

Comment: @joran, unfortunately, same error.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/blob/master/R/ConnectionWrite.R#L220) is the source of the problem, I think. Investigating...

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way around this, other than perhaps pre-cleaning the text file so that the `na.strings` argument isn't needed. Either way, might be worth creating an issue on github about it...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help @joran! BTW, do you think the "expected 20 columns of data but found 18" error has something to do with this?

Comment: I suspect that's a separate problem, but probably one that will also need to be addressed. I would try just reading in a few dozen lines near the problem line using `skip` and `nrow` and seeing if you can narrow it down. Usually that sort of thing comes down to a weird character or missing delimiter in your file or something.